# What is the proper way to restrict API access based on user type?

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose I have two users, A and B.

A is allowed to access all the resources available, but B can access them only partially.

What is the proper way to prevent B from accessing resources to which B does not have permission?

Should I create some sort of whitelist that specifies only URLs B can access?

The following snippet is what I currently have.
It is a middleware which checks whether each request is allowed to access specific URLs.

```
const ALLOWED_URLS = ['api/resource1', 'api/resource2', 'api/resource3'];
const sessionCheck = (req, res, next) => {
   const url = req.originalUrl;
   // check whether accessing URL is allowed
}
```

Is there any better approach than this?

Answer (score 6):

What you're asking about is called IAM (Identity & Access Management).
The roles, ownership, and permissions on specific resources is generally persisted in your database as business domain objects of their own. This is language agnostic and not specific to node or express. You should NOT build a white list of URLs. The resources you want to protect are in your database. You should map them to permission objects that in turn map to users. Your not protecting URLs, your protecting resources. Everyone is allowed to access any URL but the resources behind them are what you're protecting and those rules/permissions go in your database.

If your looking for industry standards then here are some common names/terms for those IAM objects that would be persisted in your DB:

- Group
- Role
- User
- Policy

User A's access would generally be determined by what role they have or what group they belong to. Whether you give user A a role, put them in an authorized group, or give them a direct permission doesn't really matter, these groupings exist to reduce duplication so you can pass around or take away multiple permissions at once. But the general idea is the same; your resources exist in a DB and you specify what is the required or allowed roles, groups, and users that can access those resources and you map users to groups, roles, etc as simple table entries. This means the real authorization logic is not in Node or Express or even in your webapp, its built into the resources themselves and tied to how the data is retrieved.

**Resource Retrieval Code**

When anyone makes a request for a given resource the query, regardless of your database type, should fail if the user is not authorized. This means the way you are retrieving data must be directly tied to how its authorized and not two separate steps; meaning you should not get the resource, then check if the user is authorized and you should not check if the user is authorized before getting the resource. The best practice is fuse/join the two so that you can not get the resource unless your authorized because we look for the resource using your role and if you don't have the right role we can't find the resource.

**For example:**

```
function getAccount(userId,accountId) {
     makeSQLCall(userId,accountId)
}

SELECT * 
FROM accounts a 
WHERE a.accountId = accountId AND u.userId = userId
JOIN users u ON a.allowedRole = u.role
```

The SQL doesn't matter as the same can be done with other technologies but the last line is the most important `(account.allowedRole = user.role)`. You literally pull the resource from the database using the users role so that if they are not authorized this fails and no data is returned. This is also your base/parent data retrieval function so other functions that don't know about authorization can use this function and authorization will be dealt with under the hood.

**Express Pseudo Code**

```
router.get('/api/resource1',function(req,res){
      var user = utility.getUserFromRequest(req)
      var resource = accountService.getAccount(user,req.body.accountId)
      sendResponse(resource)
})
```

Looking at the code above the authorization is built into your domain model not your web application. If the user making the request above is not authorized they will get no data back. You have to figure out in your own business use case is it enough to return an empty result or do you need to return a 401 HTTP error code. If you need to inform your non-malicious users they are not authorized you can simply perform `isAuthoriized(user,accountId)` before running `accountService.getAccount` as a UI convenience. The strength of this approach is that if you or some other developer forgets to check isAuthorized 1st the call will still return no data since isAuthorized() is just for the users benefit and not security. The security is at the domain/db layer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would build user resource routes and validate their ownership when you authenticate and their permissions on authorization.

E.g.

```
server.get('api/v0/products/:user', authMiddleware, (req, res, next) => {
   // from the auth middleware comes a parsed token with payload 
   if (req.payload.user !== req.params.user) {
      return res.status(401).send('not allowed')
   }

   // do action
})
```

An alternative would be to only access database objects that matches the payload of your authentication

The example would suggest using [JWT middleware](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) with a custom property `user`